# Is there any way to return a truncated string in JSON Eloquent output?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have got a `NewsItem` Model with a property `content` of a `text` type. It's long.

Now, I want to return the whole `content` in the `show` action, but in the `index` action I want to return only the first eg. 100 chars of the `content` field.

I know I can use an accessor but I guess it will affect the `show` action, too.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I think an accessor would be the best solution. Someone may have a better one though.

Create a separate accessor called something like 'excerpt', use that one in `index` and use 'content' in `show`

```
public function getExcerptAttribute()
{
    return  str_limit($this->attributes['content'], 100, '...');
}
```

Comment: Yeah but this is the main problem: how to display different attributes in different actions? Is there a better solution than iterating through all rows and manually changing their attributes?

Comment: In `index` I'm assuming you're returning a collection of eloquent models and in `show` you're returning a single model? You could create a custom collection for that model that filters/modifies the attributes or toArray method - see: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the value before returning in the index method. This should work, unless you have a mutator for the `content` attribute, that will interfere with this somehow:

```
$item->content = substr($item->content, 0, 100); 
return $item;
```

This is fine for a single use case. If you find you need to do it in other locations, then you should add a method to your model which handles this for you, or even possibly a new model, which extends the NewsItem model, and has a set or get mutator for the content attribute.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So now I've got such a problem: I want do display different properties in the `index` and diffrent ones in the `show` action. I would like to do the same with `article` and other models. Do you think It's a good idea to create nested model classes with different $static::visible array?

Comment: I would only use the nested models if you need the same results for the show action somewhere else in your application. That way you reduce redundancy. You can make use of Eloquent's `setVisible()` and `setHidden()` methods to alter what's visible: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2011, https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2000